# How to stop a user from hitting enter on a Python Command Line program?

Tags: python

Okay, so basically I'm writing an interactive Python program. Initially I will ask the user to enter their name, but even if they don't enter anything and just press enter, the program will still continue. How do I force them to hit enter?

Comment: how do you mean force them to hit enter, do you mean make sure they enter something other than an empty string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the length of your variable is greater than 0.

To find the length of a string, use `len(myStringVar)`. See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) for more if you are curious.

To repeatedly prompt until they enter a name, you could do something like this:

```
user_name = ""
while len(user_name) == 0:   # While the user_name var is empty
    user_name = raw_input('Enter a user name: ')  # Prompt the user to enter a name, and assign to the user_name var
```

A more pythonic way of this might be:

```
user_name = ""
while not user_name:  # Empty strings evaluate to False
    user_name = raw_input('Enter a user name: ')
```